# Django Rest Framework: How to add ManyToMany relationships?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

I want to add a Many To Many relation ship using Django Rest Framework. What is the best way to achieve this?

On a Django shell level what I want to do is to say `ModelA.model_bs.add(model_b)`. How can this be done?

I have achieved this using a `generic.CreateAPIView` and overwriting the `perform_create()` method like this:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
  model_a = self.get_object()
  model_b = ModelB.objects.get(uuid=serializer.validated_data["model_b"]["uuid"])
  model_a.modelbs.add(model_b)
```

It's just this feels weird, since `serializer.save()` no longer gets called this way. Is this a good way? If not, how should I go about achieving this? I couldn't find anything about this in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if there is something more complicated going on because you have not shown your models, but for a simple `ManyToMany` relation the easiest solution is just to use a [`PrimaryKeyRelatedField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield).  Something like:

```
class ModelASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model_b = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=False)
```

Then you would add an object to this field via the API via an update.

**Update**

If it is important to use the `uuid` field instead of exposing primary keys on the API, I would suggest using the [SlugRelatedField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) which is designed "to represent the target of the relationship using a field on the target":

```
class ModelASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model_b = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many=True, 
        slug_field='uuid',
        queryset=ModelB.objects.all()
    )
```

NOTE: for `SlugRelatedField`, `read_only` defaults to `False`, but you *do* need to specify a queryset.

Comment: Nothing complicated going on with my models. Thank you very much for the tip of using an update route! Unfortunately I can't use a PrimaryKeyRelatedField, since we have a strict policy of releasing pk's in our company. So the outer world must not no the key.

Comment: I've updated to add a version which takes your restriction into account.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that like the following:

> Models

```
from django.db.models import Model, ManyToManyField


class Employee(Model):
    company = ManyToManyField(Company)
```

> Serializers

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer, IntegerField, RelatedField


class CompanyRelatedField(RelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        data = {
            'id': obj.id,
            'title': obj.title
        }
        return data

    def to_internal_value(self, id):
        return Company.objects.get(id=id)


class EmployeeSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    id = IntegerField(read_only=True)
    company = CompanyRelatedField(
        queryset=Company.objects.all(), many=True, required=True
    )
```